# Xtend - saved files contain repeated data

Tags: eclipse, xtext, xtend

I don't know why when I generate files `fsa.generateFile(fileName, finalString)` it creates the files fine, but when I clean the project, it doubles the output.

Even if I delete the file, it continues growing.

Is this a code or Eclipse problem?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please give more context or share a reproducing sample project

Comment: you can also debug EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I uploaded the code here: https://github.com/Gricel-lee/Kanoa/tree/main/Resources/1%20DSL%20Generation

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to debug EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2, please?

Comment: simply set a breakpoint there and start the runtime eclipse in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you store the file content for some reason as a member in the generator and never reset it

```
val root = resource?.allContents?.head as ProblemSpecification;
s += readFile(path_sigAlloyDeclaration+"sigAlloyDeclaration.txt")
```

i assume s either should be local to the `doGenerate` method or be reset at the start

```
s = ""
val root = resource?.allContents?.head as ProblemSpecification;
s += readFile(path_sigAlloyDeclaration+"sigAlloyDeclaration.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you! Reset the string s worked! For some reason I thought that it was initialised automatically when the Eclipse run environment was stopped, but no. Thanks!